# save a tuple to a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, tuples

Is there a way to save a tuple to a django model?

**example:**

```
Class User(models.Model):
  location = models.tupleField()
```

where `User.location = (longitude, latitude)`

Comment: What do you expect the representation in the DB to be? I.e. what data type?

Comment: i'm not sure of the options i have, could please give me a hint.

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Either you create a custom field which converts the tuple from/to a single value (e.g. its string representation) upon reading/writing, or you use two fields/DB-columns.

Comment: i'm using the two fields approach already, but i thought if such thing exists it would spare me a lot of fields in my models

Comment: You can store the location in a single field if you use GIS enabled database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [GeoDjango's PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

Class User(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(help_text="Represented as (longitude, latitude)”)
```

Comment: note: this is for a tuple of 2 numbers

Comment: @merhoo You are right, an example would be helpful here. I don't use Django nowadays. Could you test and add an example? I guess it's user.location = (45, 19) or user.location = Point(45, 19)

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, i didn't see tupleField in django documentation. I think better approach is add two fields
`longitude` and `latitude` or create another model to store location and in `User` model add `ForeignKey`.

Comment: i'm using the two fields approach already, but i thought if such thing exists it would spare me a lot of fields in my models, the foreignKey solution will take space much more than needed

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the need to save tuples in a single field, you should really look into relationships. That's the reason they were created.

**Old answer:**

This answer is assuming you're really saving locations.

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can use [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/). [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) and Oracle has spacial fields built-in.

Django already supports Geo data. E.g. -

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class ModelName(models.Model):
    centroid = models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you can make all sorts of geo queries(e.g. find places that are within a specified area, sorted by distance etc) and your DBMS will take care of them. Plus from that single field, you can access your data like -

```
lat, long = [modelobject.centroid.x, modelobject.centroid.y]
# Or you can just use .x or .y directly
```

You can read more about them in the [Geodjango documentation](http://geodjango.org/).

Comment: the thing is it's not only locations, in fact most of the cases they are Strings

Comment: Sorry, then this answer serves no purpose. In case of strings, if you feel the need of saving multiple values in a single field, you need to look into relations deeper. Not having multiple values in a single field in the first form of database normalization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Django-Geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) app, and for extra, you can see the Latitude and Longitude in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66427185/5519739) could help here as well.

--

As [@p14z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862664/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-tuple-in-an-attribute-instance-in-django#comment105856850_59862664) suggests, the best way to save my `tuple` was the `ArrayField`. For my example, I just wanted to save a Polygon **extent**, with this format:

`(3.7739613717694787, 50.31527681737183, 4.726162032377, 50.49743217278623)`

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
my_tuple_field = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), size=4, null=True)
```