# Is there a way to store a tuple in an attribute instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, tuples

I am wondering if it is possible to store a tuple in a attribute instance in Django?

Something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    my_tuple_field = TupleField()
```

and then create an instance of MyModel as follow:

```
an_instance = MyModel.objects.create(my_tuple_field=('foo', 'bar'))
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using Postgres as your DB you can use the array field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield, If not you can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model

Answer (score 1):

As [@p14z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862664/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-tuple-in-an-attribute-instance-in-django#comment105856850_59862664) suggests, the best way to save my `tuple` was the `ArrayField`. For my example, I just wanted to save a Polygon **extent**, with this format:

`(3.7739613717694787, 50.31527681737183, 4.726162032377, 50.49743217278623)`

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
my_tuple_field = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), size=4, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONField if you are using PostgreSQL, or you can very easily encode a list or tuple  as a JSON list and store it in a CharField:

```
obj.foo_list = json.dumps( (2,3,4)) # "[2, 3, 4]"
obj.save()

obj = Foo.objects.get( ...)
foo_tuple = tuple( json.loads( obj.foo_list))
```

You can encapsulate this behaviour in a model property (with getter and setter), or you can build it in to model instance creation and save.

The main difference between JSONField and CharField containing JSON, is to what extent you can filter a queryset based on the contents  of the  field. PostgreSQL JSONfield allows much greater precision.